# Game Audio Course

Tags: game, course

Hi

I'd like to know some info as to break into the Game Audio industry. I'm an electronic music producer for the past 6 years and also an avid gamer! Been very keen to pursue this field, but i'm not quite sure how to go about it. I've also designed sound for an small X-box title, where my main job was to create all te sounds/scores for the entire game, and the developer had to just merely put the sounds with the tools. I'm guessing that apart from the producing the music bit, there has to be certain tools and techniques that need to be learnt to have the overall knowledge as to how to design sound for the game. Hence, i've been looking for courses specifically for this. Unfortunately, i've found only 2-3 schools giving a special course on game audio design. One of them being VFS, which is a bit too expensive for me to pursue.

so are there any other reasonably priced institutes providing courses specialising in Game Audio Design ? IS there any way or any place/studio offering internships for the same ? I'm based in India, and unfortunately, there are no such institutes catering to this, despite having a big upcoming gaming market.

Any info/help/suggestion would be appreciated. I've tried to find out through several sites, forums etc etc, but only just got a small picture. I guess this is the most ideal place to ask.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Leonard Paul and Gordon Durity, 2 of the bigger names in game audio (as I understand it anyway), have this online course: http://school.videogameaudio.com/apply

That aside, I'd say keep practicing your sound design skills on trailers etc (plenty to download at www.gametrailers.com), and start looking at the tools used by games developers. Wwise and FMOD are two to get you started, and both can be downloaded for free. There are also a bunch of tutorials on YouTube about the different things you can do with them.

And if you're on Twitter, follow @lostlab The guy is a seemingly endless fountain of game audio knowledge.

Links: www.audiokinetic.com for Wwise and www.fmod.org for FMOD.

EDIT: This one is good too, how Joshua Davidson at Gearbox got into games. Well worth a read: http://joshuadav.tumblr.com/post/8072664655/how-i-made-it-into-games-plus-a-few-things

Comment: updated with Leonard's comment - the course is now open to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Pinnacle College has a comprehensive game audio program http://www.pinnaclecollege.edu/video-game-sound-design-programs - A lot of schools offer just a few classes in game audio or you need to enroll in a program not totally dedicated to interactive/game audio but as an adjunct or a minor.

There are also a lot of really good DIY type courses - check out https://www.macprovideo.com/tutorials/gameaudio-application - I would go through their materials first since you can buy a subscription for just $25/mo - and they have lots of other audio courses as well.

I totally get the frustration you are going through in trying to find a dedicated game audio program. Pinnacle College's program is a certificate (they also have an option for an AAS degree), so it is not necessarily going to be inexpensive. However the good news is that they can accommodate international students and arrange the visa, etc.

Pinnacle College believes in you developing a demo reel or sample portfolio that demonstrates your knowledge of the main disciplines of game audio - dialogue, music composition, and field recording. Part of the program is developing a, "...portfolio that showcases their ability to create polished original content targeted for the video game community." This is where Pinnacle College appears to excel since I haven't seen a lot of other schools that even talk about how important that is outside of everyone saying you need it and to do it, but you have to do it on your own. I think a lot of schools focus on learning the software because teaching innovation and creativity (essential for developing your portfolio) is so subjective and also difficult to do in a single class or course or online. You don't want to run around telling people you know FMOD and not be able to creatively demonstrate it in your portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

@Sumith: Thanks for the mention @Joe.  This is Leonard Paul of the School of Video Game Audio.  It is true that we are currently running a private beta for the school just to polish things up before the school launches in 2012.

I happen to have a lot of free material already available on my website at http://VideoGameAudio.com which might be of use while you're looking for a school.  I would also recommend Damien's feed on Twitter for current updates: http://twitter.com/lostlab.  There's also great information available on Karen Collins' site at: http://www.gamessound.com/.  If you're interested in books, the ones featured on her site are a good way to get started.

To keep things affordable for our school, applicants who pay the registration fee will have access to most of the school curriculum for a while.  This would allow you to survey the material on the site and get a good idea of what the courses have to offer.  For people that are interested in getting feedback on their work, courses will run every few months and participants will receive qualitative assessments on their projects oriented to help them succeed in the game audio industry.

As far as Gordon Durity's qualifications and my own, feel free to do some research online.  I have personally taught at the Vancouver Film School, the Art Institute and Emily Carr University over the past few years and I feel that an online school is a great way that we can share our knowledge with people wanting to know more about video game audio in an affordable manner.

If you would like to know more, you can sign up for more information on our site and reserve your spot for when the school launches in 2012:
http://School.VideoGameAudio.com.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sumith!

Maybe it can help you:
http://designingsound.org/2011/11/full-scholarship-challenge-by-soundcloud-and-vancouver-film-school/

:)

Answer (score 0):

Hey,

We offer this sound design course -

http://www.pointblankonline.net/sound-design-course.php

it's not specifically game audio sound design, but it does cover the topic, along with all other areas.

It uses Native Instruments Kontakt and Reaktor.  Recent student successes include the wall's sausage TV advert and the Swatch TV advert.

Take a look, and get in touch if you need any more info.